# Should I use “purchase” or “buy”?

Tags: word-choice, articles

Here are my constructions:

> 1. I should like to know whether it is possible to purchase this
>      workshop manual.
> 2. I should like to know whether it is possible to buy this workshop
>      manual.

So my question is, should I use 'purchase' or 'buy'?

Also, am I missing any articles in this letter?

Full context:

> Dear Sir or Madam,
>  I have a question concerning workshop
>   manuals for Pontiac. Manual for this car model was
>   previously only available on the website at: [...]. On the website was
>   information that manual provides overview of [engine model] engine.
>
> I should like to know whether it is possible to purchase this workshop
>   manual.
>
> Thank you for your time and I am looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Is there a reason that one seems better than the other to you?

Comment: Give us a bit more context. It's nigh on impossible to tell you which is better. Rule of thumb: "purchase" is a bit more formal than "buy".

Comment: Related, from English.SE: [Is “purchased” more formal than “bought?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122781/is-purchased-more-formal-than-bought)

Comment: In another matter, *I would like to know* is much more common and less stuffy, at least in American English.

Comment: That sounds like a good match for *purchase*. Also we don't do general proofreading on this site, but you need an article before a singular count noun, *ie* your first two uses of 'manual'. I suggest *the*. And your use of 'overview', for which I suggest *an*. Note you have *a* before 'question'  which is correct.

Comment: And if I was in an antique shop (or somewhere else where it was unclear whether the item I was looking at was for sale or not) I might just ask, "Is this for sale?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Purchase" and "buy" mean the same thing. Either sentence is fine. "Purchase" is a little more formal.

BTW In the full text you gave, you're missing some articles it should be:

> Dear Sir or Madam,
> I have a question concerning workshop manuals for Pontiac. THE manual for this car model was previously only available on the website at: [...]. On the website was information that THE manual provides AN overview of THE [engine model] engine.
>
> I should like to know whether it is possible to purchase this workshop manual.
>
> Thank you for your time and I am looking forward to your answer.